# Deserialize the JSON data encapsulated in the request body into two different model object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am learning SpringBoot and am doing this coding challenge. So far, I have successfully set up the controller and have done the mapping.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/mydomain")
public class PaymentController {

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/ingest")
public void ingestData(@RequestBody String data) {
  System.out.println("ingest Data");
  System.out.println(data);

  // List<Orders>
  // List<Returns>
}

 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/query")
public String queryData(@RequestBody String data) {
  // look at LIST of order and return..and return something
}
```

}

The String data is JSON and it contains two different *types* - Order and Return.

```
{
"entries": {

    {
        type: "ORDER",
        name: "order_1",
        "attributes": {
            "owner": "John"
        }
    },
    {
        type: "ORDER",
        name: "order_2",
        "attributes": {
            "owner": "Mike",
            "buyer": "Bob"
        }
        // attributes is a key/value pair Map
    },
    {
        type: "RETURN",
        name: "return_1",
        "attributes": {
            "user": "kelly",
            "time": "null",
            "inputs": [
                "USD",
                "EUR"
            ],
            "outputs": [
                "CAD",
                "GBP"
            ]
        }
        // attributes is a key/value pair Map
    },
}
```

}

In ingestData(), I want to parse though the json and create 2 lists - one each for orders and returns. In the past, I have dealt with the all the items in the json mapping to the same Java class. How do I parse and map json items into 2 different java classes?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rethink your REST api setup a bit. It's better to create endpoints based on classes rather than have generic endpoints that process multiple. Although this might look like more work now it will really help you generate more maintainable code. The fact that you now run into this problem where you want an ObjectMapper to resolve to different classes from a single Json is a good indicator that you're going in the wrong direction.

There is a great REST API design best-practices here on Stack available

Answer (score 0):

[JsonString] -some json parsing libraries-> [Collection<Entity>] -.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy())-> [Map<String(type),Collection<Entity>>]

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html